# Storyboard preview differs from simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I'm currently trying to grapple with constraints (using Xcode 6 GM seed).  Using reset to suggested constraints, everything looks right in the universal storyboard and in the preview:
[image: storyboard]

[image: storyboard previews]

As you can see, I'm previewing for multiple screen sizes.  All of them have the image of the dot (and the image itself takes up the whole view, set to draw in the center) in the center.  However, when I load it on the simulator, I see:

[image: simulator]

I'm not sure why this is happening.  As far as I can tell, the constraints are all as they should be:

[image: constraints]

[image: constraint_1]
[image: constraint_2]
[image: constraint_3]
[image: constraint_4]

Is there something I am doing?  Or is there a bug here in xcode 6?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is happening to me all over the place. I was just about to create a question of my own!

Comment: :(  I suspect that there are troubles with constraints and simulator vs preview in 6.0.1 still, that are not (just) a product of my own ignorance.

Comment: Any update? Preview is even off from my devices on my project.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add Leading, trailing, and vertical space constraints. To place your dot in center you  need to add Horizontal and Vertical center in container constraint. Place your dot in the center of controller and add these two like in the given image. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard "Preview" doesn't match the simulator if you have any constraint errors/conflicts. I was having this problem, and found this question while searching for an answer. 
One I got all of the conflicts resolved, the Preview worked. It still seems like the preview should consistently show what the simulator would show to help during the setup.